# Dedicated Hosting offering Intel Core 2 Quad @ 6GHz. Is this real?

Tags: hardware

sorry if this is a very dumb question, but...

I just got an offer from a dedicated hosting company, offering me a box with "2 Core 2 Quad processors @ 6GHz"

I didn't know we could get 6GHz, and some googling turned out a bunch of people getting that, after overclocking like crazy, which seems to confirm my suspicion.

Are there hostings offering 6GHz CPUs, or are these people outright lying to me?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like they're being shady and assuming their customers will believe that 2 cores running at 3 ghz is the same as 6 ghz total, or they're fudging virtual numbers together. I knew someone who liked saying he had a server running 2 ghz with 2 SMP 1 ghz processors...dude, it's not the same! But he wouldn't listen.

Comment: Yep, thought the same thing, but wanted to make sure before yelling at them :-) THanks!

Comment: If its a reasonable price i would almost purchase this just for the hilarity that would ensure when i contact technical support. "Um. Your processors aren't giving me 6ghz..."

Comment: Ha, yeah. Not a reasonable price. At all. Competitive for the regional market (i'm in Argentina), not cheap enough for the laughs ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no known Intel CPU running at that frequency, and I don't think there will ever be, as the actual tendency is to *lower* clock frequency while multiplying cores.

Either there's an error on the offer, or they think four cores running at 1,5 Ghz make a total frequency of 6 Ghz (which is, of course, a really stupid idea).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought. I also think they may've chosen to multiply the frequency by the number of cores, but I wanted to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

***2 cores times 3.0 Ghz = 6.0Ghz!***

This is what you get when the ad copy is written entirely by marketing.  No, there are no commercial 6.0ghz parts available from Intel (as of yet).

Comment: Yes, i'm afraid that's what happened, but I wanted to double check before insulting them :-)